# how do I get my bootstrap.css to show in nodes/express/ jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, pug

I can't seem to get my server to render my bootstrap.css. I feel like it has something to do with the order of my scripts, but maybe I am wrong. Here is my jade file, which is where I feel my problem is. If you need more code, like the actual bootstrap in the public folder, or anything let me know.

**Jade**

```
extends layout

    block sources

        link(rel= "stylesheet prefetch", href= "stylesheets/A6/bootstrap.css")
        link(rel= "stylesheet", href="/stylesheets/A6/a6.css") 


        block content


            p#title.col-xs-12.bg-primary.text-center
            | Tic - Tac - Toe!
            div.col-xs-3.bg-info
            div.bg-primary.controls
                span
                button.btn.btn-default(data-bind="click: StartMessage.bind($root)")
                    | New Game
                p#message.lead(data-bind="if: theMessage.mainMessage")
                    |Welcome to Tic Tac Toe! This is a 2-player game. Press the "New Game" button above to play.
                p#message2.lead(data-bind="if: theMessage.player1Message")
                    |Player 1, it's your turn.
                p#message3.lead(data-bind="if: theMessage.player2Message")
                    |Player 2, it's your turn.
                p#message4.lead(data-bind="text: theMessage.playerWinMessage()")

                p#message5.lead(data-bind="text:theMessage.drawMessage()")

                h1 Score
                table#score
                    tr
                    th Player 1
                    th Player 2
                    tr
                    td#p1(data-bind="text:player1Score") 
                    td#p2(data-bind="text:player2Score")

            table.bg-success(data-bind="css:{unclickable: playerWin()}" style="table-layout:fixed;")
            tr#row1(data-bind="foreach:topRow")
                td(data-bind="text:symbol,click:$parent.PlayerTurn")
            tr#row2(data-bind="foreach:middleRow")
                td(data-bind="text:symbol,click:$parent.PlayerTurn")    
            tr#row3(data-bind="foreach:bottomRow")
                td(data-bind="text:symbol,click:$parent.PlayerTurn")



                script(src="/javascripts/A6/knockout.js")
                script(type='text/javascript', src="/javascripts/A6/a6.js")
```

So I guess my question is, would this code cause any problems with my program?

**Express**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var a1 = require('./routes/a1');
var a2 = require('./routes/a2')
var a3 = require('./routes/a3')
var a4 = require('./routes/a4')
var a5 = require('./routes/a5')
var a6 = require('./routes/a6')

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/a1',a1);
app.use('/a2',a2);
app.use('/a3',a3);
app.use('/a4',a4);
app.use('/a5',a5);
app.use('/a6',a6);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

EDIT: Added Express Code. Used express generator so its all pretty basic.

**CSS from public folder**

```
body {
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 628px;
}
.unclickable {
  pointer-events: none;
}
#title.col-xs-12.bg-primary.text-center {
  line-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: solid black 1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
}
div.col-xs-3.bg-info {
  height: 501px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
div.col-xs-3.bg-info div.bg-primary.controls {
  height: 475px;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  padding: 10px;
}
div.col-xs-3.bg-info div.bg-primary.controls button.btn.btn-default {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div.col-xs-3.bg-info div.bg-primary.controls p.lead {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
table.bg-success {
  height: 501px;
  width: 75%;
}
table.bg-success td {
  border: solid black 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8em;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 34%;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
table#score {
  height: 100px;
  width: 95%;
}
table#score th {
  border-bottom: solid black 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
table#score #p1 {
  border-right: solid black 2px;
}
table#score td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

EDIT 2: Added css file from public folder

Comment: lets see the express code, and is the other css file loading?
you might need to put a '/' in front of the bootstrap css path...

Comment: Might be pedantic but the server isn't going to "render" your bootstrap asset, it's just going to serve it. The jade syntax looks fine so like the above comment notes, check your `app.use` express syntax and directory structure. But if you're talking about straight up including the whole bootstrap library inline you can `include` it with jade.

Comment: Is the bootstrap file 404? `app.use(express.static('stylesheets'));`?

Comment: or this: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` point it to your stylesheet though, not public

Comment: So first off I should say, My other files work perfectly, it is just this one that doesn't work. Thats why I assume its in this file, but I could be wrong. @anthonygore I tried changing that to stylesheets but had no luck

Comment: Place your bootstrap stylesheet in public folder and then try to load it..

Comment: Actually I guess it could be a problem with my personal css files, they were compiled down from LESS so its a possibility. I've added that as well

Comment: @mauliksakhare I am not sure what you mean.. I thought it goes without saying but I did actually put the bootstrap file in the folder, Im aware of this prerequisite.

Comment: Check your developer console and see if you're getting a 404 on your css file. If so, it probably means it's probably not being served. If it's actually loaded, perhaps there was a problem compiling from LESS etc.

Comment: Yes the css file is being served, and I checked the css and everything in codepen (heres the link: http://codepen.io/jkwest30/pen/qZqKro?editors=0100) and it works perfectly.

Comment: add / to the beginning of the href bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I have added the style sheets loader in my layout template under the head tag:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css')enter code here
```